# filenames to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, bash

How do I write a script in either bash or php that goes through each filename in a folder and adds it to a mysql db?

The filenames are such as "Avfärd Italienresan.mp4". That name, without the .mp4 suffix, will work for the "name" column. It should convert "åäö" characters to "aao". I also have a "file" column in the db, which should be a "server friendly" reference, such as "avfard_italienresan".

So in theory I'd assume it to be like..

```
for each
input filename > Avfärd Italienresan.mp4
db column name > Avfärd Italienresan
db column file > avfard_italienresan
next..
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I know how it should work in practice, but the actual syntax and to make it all work together is over my head. I used the "detox -rs lower" command, that rendered the filenames nicely. I then did the "find > textfile.txt" thing to output it to a textfile. But how to read each line in a textfile and import that to a db, including the original filename, is a little more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP [glob()](http://php.net/glob) function to get all files from a folder

```
$files = glob(directory_path."/*"); // get all files in a folder
```

// Loop through array of fetched files and insert into database.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filename = basename($file);

    // WRITE YOU MySQL code here that inserts filenames into DB

}
```

[MySQL Insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)